# Unexpected token import error in while running jest tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, babel-jest

I know this has been asked countless times, but I am not able to fix the problem inspite of following all the SO solutions and suggestions.

I came to know about `jest` a few days ago and tried to have my hands on it. There is a good tutorial mentioned on [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/testing-react-applications-with-jest) about using `jest` to test react components. However, when I try testing one of the components from the `starter` directory, I am having this issue,

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
>
> at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
>         at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)

As per suggested in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460420/babel-loader-jsx-syntaxerror-unexpected-token), I have already installed `babel-preset-react` and added it to my `webpack.config.js` file.

Here is my [`webpack.config.js`](https://gist.github.com/zac11/1924067cdb23f335e030ed0500ce4dc8) file, my [`package.json`](https://gist.github.com/zac11/c5cd99c305cf303e8d2113d613268d71) file , the [`.babelrc`](https://gist.github.com/zac11/e94e7e8a7558a8c7e0208eae7b3a7d67) file

Please note that I have already gone through the solutions posted in these SO posts -

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725796/jest-test-suite-failed-to-run-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040978/babel-unexpected-token-import-when-running-mocha-tests)
- [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460420/babel-loader-jsx-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

which might be apparent from the changes in my `.babelrc` and `webpack` files

But I'm not able to fix the issue that I'm having. Please let me know if I am missing something here, since I have spent a good 3-4 hrs searching SO and other forums for any answer and I can't seem to find it.

[image: Image Link]

Update 1: Here is my test file - `Clock.test.jsx`

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import Clock from 'Clock';

 describe('Clock',()=>{
      it("renders without crashing",()=>{
         const div = document.createElement('div');
         ReactDOM.render(<Clock/>,div);
      });
   });
```

Comment: Can you link to the test file, I suspect you're not importing at the top level of the module which is against the spec. You can change that by setting the loose property to true in babel.

Comment: @AaronFupdated the test file in question.

Comment: Your configs are very messy. 1. Fix your package.json dependencies... get rid of that preset stuff, the package.json is not a configuration for your loader! Replace it with the Babel version (you really don't even need that npm package). 2. Get rid of the query in your webpack config!

Comment: What changes should I make. It would be good if you can add those in your answer please. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was trying to follow up that tutorial but could not even install it without errors. As I see it, the tutorial is old, webpack 1 is deprecated, and other packages also undergone changes. You could try my steps, but it may not work for you.

- In the starter/CountdownTimer folder run `npm install`. If it throws 
  this errors: “Cannot read property 'find' of undefined”, then run `npm cache verify` and `npm install`.
- Then run `npm install –save-dev jest@18.0.0` to install jest.
- In the app folder create `__tests__` folder in there create app.test.jsx
  and Clock.test.jsx.
- Add `“jest”` to the package.json test script.
- Change your .babelrc.

Here is how the files look like:

```
// app.test.jsx
describe('App', () => {
    it('should be able to run tests', () => {
        expect(1 + 2).toEqual(3);
    });
});

// Clock.test.jsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// Note the path.
import Clock from '../components/Clock';

describe('Clock',()=>{
  it("renders without crashing",()=>{
     const div = document.createElement('div');
     ReactDOM.render(<Clock/>,div);
  });
});

// package.json
{
  "name": "countdown-timer",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "Joyce Echessa",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "react": "^15.4.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "foundation-sites": "^6.2.4",
    "jest": "^18.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "sass-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "script-loader": "^0.7.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webpack": "^1.13.3"
  }
}

// .babelrc
{
    "presets": [["es2015"], ["react"]]
}
```

Run `npm test`. This worked for me to get tests passing, hope it will help you too.

Comment: This error basically tells that import is not been transpiled. It can happen if there is no “es2015” in your presets. See my edited answer.