# How to use Jest to test Javascript ES6?

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6, syntax-error, jestjs

I want to use the Jest testing framework to test vanilla Javascript (not React). I'm getting an error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import`.

My file is called `functionName.js` and my test file is called `functionName.test.js`. Both are in the same folder. I used `export const functionName` and `import functionName from './functionName.js'` to export/import the function I'm testing. It works fine when I use `module.exports = functionName` and `const functionName = require('./functionName.js')` but that's ES5 notation and I want to write it in ES6.

I'm new to using Jest, so any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: This is a deep rabbit hole. Basically the code still needs to be transpiled to a supported format.

Comment: I have had this issue before. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44476725/unexpected-token-import-error-in-while-running-jest-tests