# Material UI + Enzyme testing component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, enzyme

I have component in React which I'm trying to test with Jest, unfortunately test do not pass.

The component code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ProductItem from '../ProductItem/ProductItem';
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/es/AppBar/AppBar";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/es/Tabs/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/es/Tab/Tab";
import {connect} from 'react-redux';


class ProductsTabsWidget extends Component {

    state = {
        value: 0
    }

    renderTabs = () => {
        return this.props.tabs.map((item, index) => {
            return item.products.length > 0 ? (<Tab key={index} label={item.title}/>) : false;
        })
    }

    handleChange = (event, value) => {
        this.setState({value});
    };


    renderConentActiveTab = () => {
        if (this.props.tabs[this.state.value]) {
            return this.props.tabs[this.state.value].products.map((productIndex) => {
                return (<ProductItem key={productIndex} {...this.props.products[productIndex]} />);
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        let tabs = null;
        let content = null;
        if (this.props.tabs) {
            tabs = this.renderTabs();
            content = this.renderConentActiveTab();
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <AppBar position="static" color="default">
                    <Tabs
                        value={this.state.value}
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                        indicatorColor="primary"
                        textColor="primary"
                        centered
                        scrollButtons="auto"
                    >
                        {tabs}
                    </Tabs>
                </AppBar>
                <div className="productWidget">
                    <div className="wrapper">
                        {content}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        products: state.product.products,
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ProductsTabsWidget);
```

I have tried to write proper test for this component, the code is below:

```
import React from 'react';

import {configure, shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import ProductsTabsWidget from "./ProductsTabsWidget";


configure({adapter: new Adapter()});

describe('ProductsTabsWidget - component', () => {
    let wrapper;


    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallow(<ProductsTabsWidget/>);
    });

    it('renders with minimum props without exploding', () => {
        wrapper.setProps({
            tabs: [],
            products:[]
        });
        expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(1);
    });
})
```

But when I'm running test I am getting error:

```
Test suite failed to run

    F:\PRACA\reactiveShop\node_modules\@material-ui\core\es\AppBar\AppBar.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import _extends from "@babel/runtime/helpers/builtin/extends";
                                                                                             ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

      at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/product/ProductsTabsWidget/ProductsTabsWidget.js:3:15)
```

I have tried testing with `shallow`, `mount`, `render` but it did not help. What am I missing?

My application is created on `create-react-app`.

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token import` seems like Babel misconfiguration, which shouldn't appear on basic CRA setup, maybe you `eject`ed some of its features? Generally the issue seems to be related with configuration [jest: Test suite failed to run, SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725796/jest-test-suite-failed-to-run-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import).

Answer (score 15):

It's something different when you're using `@material-ui`.

You've to use `@material-ui`'s Built-in API(s). Such as `createMount`, `createShallow`, `createRender` in order to use enzyme's `shallow`, `mount` & `render`.

These APIs are built on top of `enzyme`, so you can't use `enzyme` directly for testing `@material-ui`.

---

#### Example of `Shallow` Rendering with @material-ui

```
import { createShallow } from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';

describe('<MyComponent />', () => {
  let shallow;

  before(() => {
    shallow = createShallow(); 
  });

  it('should work', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
  });
});
```

---

Reference: [Official Docs of @material-ui](https://material-ui.com/guides/testing/)

Comment: I know this is somewhat of an "old" post, but I don't find this to be completely true. I'm very much using material UI exposed through my own npm package in a project (called mystyle) in which I have styled my components. This package is then imported into another project (myapp) in which I perform my tests (i.e. I use my own components with material UI under the hood). The tests in myapp are written using enzyme and jest. And they work just fine.

Comment: Material-UI is deprecating their test utils and will no longer be present in v5.

Answer (score 14):

Following is a humble attempt to provide a more complete answer from `create-react-app` and `@material-ui` perspective.

`1.` Create `setupTests.js` directly in `src` folder and paste the following code.

```
import { configure } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

`2.` The following is react stateless component which uses `material-ui` components.

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const SearchField = props => (
   <TextField InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }} fullWidth
              placeholder={props.placeholder}
              onChange={props.onChange}
   />
);

export default SearchField;
```

Note that in the above component, the component expects parent component to pass the props for `placeholder` and `onChange()` event handler

`3.` Coming to the test case for for the above component we can write either in a way `material-ui` suggests or in a `pure enzyme` style. Both will work.

`Pure Enzyme` Style

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import SearchField from "../SearchField";
describe("SearchField Enzyme mount() ", () => {
  const fieldProps = {
    placeholder: "A placeholder",
    onChange: jest.fn()
  };
  const Composition = props => {
    return <SearchField {...fieldProps} />;
  };

  it("renders a <TextField/> component with expected props", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Composition />);
    expect(wrapper.childAt(0).props().placeholder).toEqual("A placeholder");
    expect(wrapper.childAt(0).props().onChange).toBeDefined();
  });
  it("should trigger onChange on <SearchField/> on key press", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Composition />);
    wrapper.find("input").simulate("change");
    expect(fieldProps.onChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
  it("should render <TextField />", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Composition />);
    expect(wrapper.find(TextField)).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(wrapper.find(TextField).props().InputProps.disableUnderline).toBe(
      true
    );
  });
});
```

`Material UI` style

```
import React from "react";
import { createMount } from "@material-ui/core/test-utils";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import SearchField from "../SearchField";
describe("SearchField", () => {
  let mount;
  const fieldProps = {
    placeholder: "A placeholder",
    onChange: jest.fn()
  };
  beforeEach(() => {
    mount = createMount();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    mount.cleanUp();
  });

  it("renders a <TextField/> component with expected props", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<SearchField {...fieldProps} />);
    expect(wrapper.props().placeholder).toEqual("A placeholder");
    expect(wrapper.props().onChange).toBeDefined();
  });
  it("should trigger onChange on <SearchField/> on key press", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<SearchField {...fieldProps} />);
    wrapper.find("input").simulate("change");
    expect(fieldProps.onChange).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

`5.` The error you are getting is due to the fact that `babel` is not getting a chance to process your file. The `create-react-app` expects you to run tests like `yarn run test` and not like `jest your/test/file.js`. If you use latter `babel` won't be `employed`.

If you want to use `jest` to run the file you will have to write a `jest.config.js` file or configure `jest` in `package.json` file to use `babel-jest` + `other babel dependencies` to transpile your code before jest tries to execute tests.

I was in the same boat yesterday as I tried to use `@material-ui` for the first time and came here to get a more complete answer.

Comment: So in your case, what command did you use to run tests? `npm test` or `yarn test`?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this worked for me:

```
import {createMount} from '@material-ui/core/test-utils';

const WrappedComponent = () => 
    <MUIThemeStuffEtc>
        <MyComponent />
    </MUIThemeStuffEtc>

const render = createMount();
const wrapper = render(<WrappedComponent />);

const state = wrapper.find(MyComponent).instance().wrappedInstance.state
```