# Svelte Component Testing with Jest, Unable to load Svelte files recursively

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, babeljs, svelte

I am working on a Svelte Project with Typescript and want to use Jest to test UI components using the [@testing-library/svelte module](https://testing-library.com/docs/svelte-testing-library/intro) . I am not able to properly import all my svelte files like my sub-components and Jest just hangs trying to load the application.

There are some typescript errors in the svelte components and by these errors printing, I can see which files actually loaded. After loading App.svelte, the program just freezes and doesn't load any of the submodules.

I am not exactly sure where the error is, because before this error I was getting an import error similar to [jest: Test suite failed to run, SyntaxError: Unexpected token import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41725796/jest-test-suite-failed-to-run-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-import), I "solved" this by adding the configuration to the .babelrc file and adding the preprocessor.

[image]

All the relevant files are below and are also on [Github here](https://github.com/Mozilla-Open-Lab-Etwas/Video-Transcoder/tree/97d72708dce3d6cb814a4dbae5ebd581cc173f4f)

The actual test case file, there is a data-testid element called dropzone in dropzone.svelte

```js
// app.spec.js
import App from "../src/App.svelte";

import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/svelte";

describe("UI Load Test", () => {
  it("Check Dropzone Loaded", () => {
    const { getByText, getByTestId } = render(App);
    const dropzone = getByTestId("dropzone");
    expect(dropzone).toBeDefined();
  });
});
```

```html
// App.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  ...

  // Static Svelte Components

  import HeaderContent from "./components/header.svelte";
  import Loader from "./components/loader.svelte";
  import Footer from "./components/footer.svelte";

  // Dynamic Svelte Modules
  import Terminal from "./modules/terminal/terminal.svelte";
  import Dropzone from "./modules/dropzone/dropzone.svelte";
  import Configure from "./modules/configure/configure.svelte";
  import Video from "./modules/video/video.svelte";
  import Progress from "./modules/progress/progress.svelte";

  let loaded = $loadedStore;
  ...
  let fileState = $fileUploaded;
  ...
  let processedState = $processed;
  ...
  let progressState = $progressStore;
  ...
  let configState = $showConfig;
  ...
</script>

...
```

```js
// jest.config.js
const {
  preprocess: makeTsPreprocess,
  createEnv,
  readConfigFile,
} = require("@pyoner/svelte-ts-preprocess");

const env = createEnv();
const compilerOptions = readConfigFile(env);
const preprocessOptions = {
  env,
  compilerOptions: {
    ...compilerOptions,
    allowNonTsExtensions: true,
  },
};
const preprocess = makeTsPreprocess(preprocessOptions);

module.exports = {
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.svelte$": [
      "jest-transform-svelte",
      { preprocess: preprocess, debug: true },
    ],
    "^.+\\.ts$": "ts-jest",
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
  },
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules"],
  bail: false,
  verbose: true,
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["node_modules"],
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "svelte", "ts"],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    "./jest.setup.js",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect",
  ],
};
```

```js
// babel.config.js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        targets: {
          node: "current",
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

```js
//.babelrc
{
    "plugins": [

        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"
    ],
    "env": {
        "test": {
            "plugins": ["dynamic-import-node"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might think about testing your components separately and mocking them, when they are used as dependency.

Comment: Do you mean not testing each module separately without importing any other svelte modules? Like for some actual node modules that can't run I do mock them, but I wanted to be able to test the entire UI/UX together. Like test the follow of the application

Comment: This sounds like you want e2e tests? There are several frameworks. Have a look at: https://www.slant.co/topics/8034/~javascript-end-to-end-testing-tools

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported these variables yet from your store.ts file "$loadedStore, $fileUploaded, $processed, $progressStore, $showConfig"

Basically, you can put this on a store.ts like this.

```
// store.ts 
export const loadedStore= writable([]) // for arrays

export const fileUploaded= writable({}) // for objects

export const processed = writable("") // for strings

export const progressStore = writable("")

export const showConfig= writable({})
```

Then add this line on top of your App.svelte file

```
// App.svelte

import { loadedStore, fileUploaded, processed, progressStore, showConfig } from 'store.ts'
```